# Why did the kohanim desire to entrap people?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The *kohanim* (priests) would have made the *ketores* (incense) have an aroma that no man would be able to resist – had it not been for the fact that the Torah prohibits it:

> וְעוֹד תָּנֵי בַּר קַפָּרָא
>  אִלּוּ הָיָה נוֹתֵן בָּהּ קוֹרְטוֹב
>   שֶׁל דְּבַשׁ 
>  אֵין אָדָם יָכוֹל לַעֲמוֹד מִפְּנֵי רֵיחָהּ 
>   וְלָמָה אֵין מְעָרְבִין בָּהּ דְּבַשׁ
>  מִפְּנֵי שֶׁהַתּוֹרָה
>   אָמְרָה
>  כִּי כָל שְׂאֹר וְכָל דְּבַשׁ לֹא תַקְטִֽירוּ מִמֶּֽנּוּ
>   אִשֶּׁה לַייָ​
>
> Bar Kappara also taught: 
>  Had [even] a minute quantity of honey
>   been added to it, 
>  no man would have been able to resist the
>   aroma.
>  Why, then, were they not to mix honey into it? 
>  Because
>   the Torah says:
>  “You shall burn no leaven or any honey as a
>   fire-offering to God.”

But if they had mixed in honey, they would have created something that no-one would be able to resist! Why would they have wanted to create a such an entrapment in the first place?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I don't understand. If it's not forbidden, what's the entrapment? Or is that why it's Purim Torah?

Comment: @msh210 No-one would have been able to resist it. *Lo Siten Michshol*...

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mistranslating לעמוד. We learn in Asher Yatzar:

> שֶׁאִם יִפָּתֵחַ אֶחָד מֵהֶם, אוֹ יִסָּתֵם אֶחָד מֵהֶם ,
>   אִי אֶפְשַׁר לְהִתְקַיֵּם וְלַעֲמוֹד לְפָנֶיך
>
> For if one (body organ) were to open, or close, it would not be possible to survive and stand before you.

Thus, the braita means that if they added honey, everyone who smelled it would die. The question is, would the Kohanim really want to kill everyone? The answer, unfortunately, is yes. As we learn in Shmuel Alef 22:17:

> ויאמר המלך... סבו והמיתו כהני יהוה
>
> And the king said... "Turn and kill, O Kohanim of Hashem."

And the next Pasuk tells us:

> וימת ביום ההוא שמנים וחמשה איש
>
> And eighty-five men died that day.

Thus, it was necessary to tell the Kohanim not to kill Bnei Yisrael.

Comment: I could have just used Shmot 32:26-28, but that would be no fun :)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider this part of Rav Dessler's Nekudat Habechirah. Had they used honey, no man would have been able to resist (though women probably would have been able). Thus they would have lost their free will and been drawn in to the mishkan. As a result, they would have been unable to choose to worship Hashem of their own free will.

Hashem had to warn the Kohanim not to add honey so that the choice to worship Hasem would still be available.

Another point is that they would have been unable to stop themselves from entering the inner area and become subject to the death penalty. The kohanim might not have realized that this would occur.